# RegEx: capture entire group content

Tags: regex, parsing

I am writing a parser for some Oracle commands, like

```
LOAD DATA
  INFILE  /DD/DATEN
TRUNCATE
PRESERVE BLANKS
INTO TABLE aaa.bbb
( some parameters... )
```

I already created a regex to match the entire command. I am now looking for a way to capture the name of the input file ("/DD/DATEN" for instance here).
My problem is that using the following regex will only return the last character of the first group ("N").

```
^\s*LOAD DATA\s*INFILE\s*(\w|\\|/)+\s*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/lEsNf8kd3qveHkGA)

Any ideas?
Many thanks in advance

EDIT: following @HamZa 's question, here would be the entire regex to parse Oracle [LOAD DATA INFILE command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/load-data.html)  (simplified though):

```
^\s*LOAD DATA\s*INFILE\s*((?:\w|\\|/)+)\s*((?:TRUNCATE|PRESERVE BLANKS)\s*){0,2}\s*INTO TABLE\s*((?:\w|\.)+)\s*\(\s*((\w+)\s*POSITION\s*\(\s*\d+\s*\:\s*\d+\s*\)\s*((DATE\s*\(\s*(\d+)\s*\)\s*\"YYYY-MM-DD\")|(INTEGER EXTERNAL)|(CHAR\s*\(\s*(\d+)\s*\)))\s*\,{0,1}\s*)+\)\s*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/idPkenInafs5MxJ3)

Comment: upvote for relevant picture in question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's point out the wrongdoer in your regex `(\w|\\|/)+`. What happens here ?
You're matching either a word character or a back/forwardslash and putting it in group 1 `(\w|\\|/)` after that you're telling the regex engine to do this one or more times `+`. What you actually want is to match those characters several times before grouping them. So you might use a non-matching group `(?:)` : `((?:\w|\\|/)+)`.

You might notice that you could just use a character class after all `([\w\\/]+)`. Hence, your regex could look like

```
^\s*LOAD DATA\s*INFILE\s*([\w\\/]+)\s*$
```

On a side note: that end anchor `$` will cause your regex to fail if you're not using multiline mode. Or is it that you intentionally didn't post the full regex  :) ?

Comment: Thanks a lot @HamZa for the comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 2):

Not tested but...

```
^\s*LOAD DATA\s*INFILE\s*(\S+)\s*$
```

Comment: Thanks @Vorsprung. However, this would not only match either characters of back/forward slashes.